# Decrease in BIC value despite very low beta-coefficient

Tags: regression-coefficients, bic

I used the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) to aide in multiple model selection. I want to predict the amount of phosphorus which is extracted by P-test A (DL-P) based on the amount that is extracted by P-test B (CAL-P) and 4 other parameters. P-test B is a fixed variable, the other variables can, but do not need to be included in the model. To assess which parameters should be included I use BIC.

[image]
First equation is the simple model, below the two equations with minimum BIC value. Second line of each equation shows the beta-coeficient of the respective regressor.

**Question: How can I explain the high ΔBIC (equation ABC compared to A), despite the very low beta-coefficients of variable B and C**

Shouldnt a beta-coefficient close to zero mean that these regressor hardly influence the target variable? However, the high ΔBIC seems to indicate differently.

Comment: Very low compared to what?

Comment: Let me rephrase.. How can I explain the high ΔBIC (equation ABC compared to A) despite the fact that the beta-coefficients of variable B and C are close to 0, and therefore have almost zero influence on the target variable.

Comment: "Almost zero" compared to what? Say, your variable has standard deviation of 0.0001 and regression coefficient for it is 0.01, then it is a HUGE effect of that variable, since it is few orders of magnitude. So I ask "small compared to what?".

Comment: The standard deviation of the relevant variables: CAL-P=5.77, pH=0.57, Corg=0.67. However, each beta is calculated by substracting the mean and dividing with the standard deviation (sd) of the variable. So why should the individal sd matter? Sorry if iam overseeing something crucial here... my stat. knowledge is admittedly patchy